# Just dropped my mac, speakers broke?

Tags: speakers, damage

I have accidentally dropped my mac in a way that it damaged my internal speakers. They're not damaged severely, but they are impared.

Basically, without headphones the right side of my MBA 11' produces sound but the left side doesn't. This is clearly evident when I plug in headphones: The left earbud produces little noise and the right earbud produces normal amounts of noise. I have verified it is the MBA that is impaired and not the headphones.

Is it repairable? I have tried restarting my macbook and it didn't help. I don't want to take it to the apple store and pay a hefty amount. What do I do?

Comment: It never hurts to get an estimate from them, and that is totally free. You can DIY it, or at least see how much Apple would charge. From the parts I've listed in my answer, it looks it would cost you about $20 if you live in the US. Apple may be able to do it for relatively cheap (maybe $50), so I'd at least see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is easily repairable. The speakers are relatively cheap. PBM sells them for $15 USD: http://www.powerbookmedic.com/MacBook-Air-11-Left-Speaker-p-22393.html (I have used them in the past for parts and highly recommend).

You can then hope to iFixit for a teardown of your MBA: http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Replacing+MacBook+Air+11-Inch+Mid+2011+Left+Speaker/6312/1

Note that the MBA is actually as moderate difficulty in repairing (by iFixit), so if you are a klutz, you may elect to have someone else do the repair for you. Also, I have used general searches for your MBA model (based on the limited information you have provided), so you should ensure the parts are the exact ones you need and not go simply on my links above.

Comment: I'm mainly concerned about listening to it with headphones. Will it fix the problem?

Comment: If the headphones show the same symptom, it is not the speakers.

Comment: Read the question @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. What is it then?

Comment: I have read the question.  The symptom is the same in the speakers and the headphones - the cause is therefore somewhere common to these two and will most likely not be fixable by changing the speakers.